# Как зафиксировать строку ввода внизу в консоли, используя bash?

Tags: bash, консоль, shell, командная-строка

Мне нужно зафиксировать вводимую в консоль команду в нижней строке, вместе с приглашением ввода, перемещая её вниз по мере вывода логов выше, как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672193/fixed-position-command-prompt-in-node-js).

Я использую [serverline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverline) в Node.js, но хочу универсальный инструмент для любого языка и виртуализации.
В идеале, хотелось бы перенаправить stdin, stdout, stderr в другую команду через bash.

Есть какие-нибудь консольные утилиты для этого?

Comment: Для управления выводом большинство терминалов используют специальные последовательности символов. Ими можно расцвечивать текст, перемещать курсор, и ещё много чего. Дабы не париться с запоминанием всех этих последовательностей есть специальные библиотеки-обёртки. Наиболее популярной такой библиотекой является [`ncurses`](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) С этой библиотекой вы и экран на окошки порежете, и строку ввода зафиксируете, и даже меню сможете организовать.

Comment: Вопрос в другом. ncurses и прочие библиотеки - программные средства, а мне нужна консольная обёртка для перехвата ввода-вывода.